# Could a Relativistic Rocket convert the heat of Doppler shifted Cosmic Background Radiation into usable energy?

Tags: special-relativity, rocket-science, cosmic-microwave-background, cosmic-rays

[This page](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html) on mathdept.ucr.edu about relativistic rockets states:

> As you approach the speed of light you will be heading into an
> increasingly energetic and intense bombardment of cosmic rays and
> other particles. After only a few years of 1 g acceleration, even the
> cosmic background radiation is Doppler shifted into a lethal heat bath
> that's hot enough to melt all known materials.

Could generators in the hull of a relativistic rocket convert this heat into usable energy? Could this provide the external energy source necessary for a relativistic rocket's continued acceleration?

Comment: Well I'm generally of the opinion that any fictitious device should be able to do whatever you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

The radiation from the front is blueshifted, but that from the back is redshifted, so the net momentum gained is in the opposite direction of motion, which results in a decelerating effect.

The photon soup acts like a perfect fluid (as which it is threated in cosmology), resulting in drag (similiar to air resistance, but without turbulences).

If you want to decelerate because you are already close to your target you can call that usefull energy, but if you want to accelerate it doesn't help.

Comment: A spacecraft can use the dynamic pressure from drag and extract enough energy to accelerate as long as it has propellant and a suitable propulsion system. [Here is a link to the concept.](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=50611.0) Not viable for relativistic speeds, but it's possible to accelerate "upstream" under the right conditions.

Comment: I was thinking that if heat were harnessed from the rocket's front and sides, more energy would be put towards propulsion than would be received from any other direction

Comment: This sounds to me like the idea of using a waterwheel to power a boat. As the boat went up stream its motion would cause the waterwheel to turn which could power the boat to move upstream.

Comment: I was hoping it could be more like if you're sailing in an ocean of gasoline, you can always put more in the gas tank